# IntegrityError at /api/shopping-cart/ (1048, "Column 'product_id' cannot be null")

Tags: django-rest-framework, angular6

I have three model. Product, ShoppingCart and CartDetails. when i add a product to cart i want to save data in ShoppingCart and CartDetails.ShoppingCart (id) is related with CartDetails (cart_id).And CartDetails (product_id) is related with Product(id). Now when i am posting data it shows the error "Column 'product_id' cannot be null". I think i am missing a silly thing. But cannot find out the silly thing. I am new to django rest framework.I am using angular for front end. I don't understand what i am doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='cat_id')
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_name/%Y/%m/%d/')
    sell_price = models.IntegerField()
    cost_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount_price = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "products"


    class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        db_table = "shopping-cart"


class CartDetails(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingCart, related_name='cart_details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        db_table = "cart-details"
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_name', 'description', 'image_url', 'sell_price', 'cost_price',
                  'discount_price', 'active', 'cat_id')


class CartDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = CartDetails
    fields = ('product', 'qty', 'amount')


class ShoppingCartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cart_details = CartDetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingCart
        fields = ('id', 'amount', 'cart_details')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        carts_data = validated_data.pop('cart_details')
        # cart = ShoppingCart.objects.create(**validated_data)
        #  for data in carts_data:
        # CartDetails.objects.create(cart=cart, **carts_data)
        return validated_data
```

views.py

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Product.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProductSerializer


class ShoppingCartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ShoppingCart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShoppingCartSerializer


class CartDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CartDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartDetailSerializer
```

This is angular service to post data

```
private create(product) {
    const cart = {
      amount: product.sell_price,
      cart_details: {
        qty: 1,
        product: product.id,
        amount: product.sell_price
      }
    };
    return this.http.post(this.globalService.baseUrl + 'shopping-cart/', cart);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, problem is here

```
product_id = ProductSerializer(read_only=True, source='product.id')
```

as you make this as read_only field, so product_id is not writing on instance creation. `read_only` should be removed.

```
product_id = ProductSerializer(source='product.id')
```

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `products` on serializer `CartDetailSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'.
Now shown this error.

Comment: by default id is associated with foreign-key if you don't explicitly used `db-column` in model field defination. please try `product = ProductSerializer()` and also in meta data just `product` should good enough.

Comment: {"cart_details":{"product":["This field is required."]}}. when i write product = ProductSerializer() it takes all field of product model. But i need only id.

Comment: are you using same serializer to retrive data ? if not then just remove nested portion of this.

Comment: No result. i just don't understand why product_id is null?? my data in json format as below:
{
    "amount": null,
    "cart_details": {
        "product": {
            "product_name": "",
            "description": "",
            "image_url": null
        },
        "qty": null,
        "amount": null
    }
}
but i think it should be like 
{
    "amount": null,
    "cart_details": {
            "product_id": "",            
            "qty": null,
            "amount": null
    }
}

Comment: can you please update  what is your request.data actually getting. I am sorry i didn't understand your reply properly.

Comment: I think previous problem is solved after updating my serializers.But till now data is not posting. 
My updated serializers 

class CartDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartDetails
        fields = ('product', 'qty', 'amount')


class ShoppingCartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cart_details = CartDetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingCart
        fields = ('id', 'amount', 'cart_details')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        carts_data = validated_data.pop('cart_details')

Comment: Can you please update your code in question section, so that your code is more readable what is actually happening. But from you response i have a sense that in your front-end code `product_id: product.id,` should be `product: product.id`

Comment: As you told i updated my code. Still error.

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `CartDetailSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'.